# Unattended upgrades: How to combat "cannot allocate memory"

Tags: server, dpkg

When running a VPS that has unattended security upgrades, it's kind of sad to come back after several months to discover that nothing has happened because system services have been "optimized" to use so much memory that DPKG cannot run the upgrade process: `cannot allocate memory`.

The quick fix is to stop a couple of system services (database/web server/CGI) to free up memory so that upgrades can run.

**What are good practices to ensure that there is always enough memory for security upgrades?**

Is there a clever way to shut down specific services during upgrades to ensure that installing security upgrades is robust and remains unattended?

Comment: Do you have swap space enabled? What's the output of `free`?

Comment: Did you fiddle around with the overcommit policy?  Normally the kernel just keeps letting applications allocate as much memory as they want and when you actually run out of memory, the OOM killer picks a process to kill to free some memory up.

Comment: Hard to know from what you posted, but either you need more RAM or swap space or some program / VM has a memory leak or sometimes services such as Apache can use up all your RAM, especially if the services is under some sort of exploit or attack (I have seen this with wordpress for example, you restart apache and RAM use goes down only to climb very high via a WP exploit requiring a patch or modification of php).

Comment: Also , I am not a fan of unattended upgrades or a policy of install an forget about it. IMO you should at least check in on your server from time to time. It is not your server's fault or ubuntu's fault you did not check your server for  several months. Consider looking at your VPS, they may also benefit from some attention =)

Comment: @Murphy no swap space, but great advice, thanks -- will see if my provider has this or just create a file-based swap.

Comment: @Panther while I agree to your comment on forgetting about one's servers is a bad idea, I think you're wrong about the unattended upgrades -- they are very helpful to get security upgrades out quickly and efficiently. I don't spend my life being on 24/7 call to do security upgrades :)

Comment: OK, as long as you have a plan it is all good. Just trying to give you some options . Did you ever figure out the issue with your memory ?

Comment: @Panther the memory issue is basically that Nginx+Postgress+Uwsgi are configured in a way that they use up almost the entire memory.. which in a sense is good because it's optimal usage of the resources... but very bad when important system tasks cannot run. So the basic problem was that there wasn't a swap.

Comment: I'm going to conclude - for now - that it's not normal to configure anything additional to guarantee that the upgrade DPKG processes have enough memory, apart from having enough swap?